# Failed to apply plugin [class 'io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.DependencyManagementPlugin']

Tags: gradle

I am very much a newbie in programming. so i need help to troubleshoot this error. Please excuse.

```
16:52:44.590 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
16:52:44.590 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
16:52:44.590 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Where:
16:52:44.590 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Build file '/opt/eventuate-examples-restaurant-management/restaurants-service/build.gradle' line: 4
16:52:44.590 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
16:52:44.590 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
16:52:44.590 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] A problem occurred evaluating project ':restaurants-service'.
16:52:44.590 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Failed to apply plugin [class 'io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.DependencyManagementPlugin']
16:52:44.590 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    > Could not create task of type 'DependencyManagementReportTask'.
16:52:44.591 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
16:52:44.591 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
16:52:44.591 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
16:52:44.591 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
16:52:44.591 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
16:52:44.591 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger]
16:52:44.591 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 2s
```

gradle version

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 3.4.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2012-12-21 00:00:00 UTC
Revision:     none

Groovy:       2.4.15
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.3 compiled on July 19 2018
JVM:          10.0.2 (Oracle Corporation 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.3)
OS:           Linux 4.15.0-1021-aws amd64
```

Comment: Attach what you have tried so far, so people can help you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be related to the Spring Boot plugin version you are using. See some issues that could be related to your problem: https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-3482  and https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin/issues/87.

So you should upgrade your plugin version, and (if possible) upgrade Gradle version to latest ( `4.10` )

Current version of the plugin is `2.1.0.RELEASE`

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.0.RELEASE'
}
```